# Como hago para manejar una lista de listas en javascript?

Tags: javascript

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Javascript, HTML,CSS y Google maps.
En dicho proyecto tengo dos listas con imágenes y texto de la siguiente forma:

```
<ul>
   <li> 
      <img>
   </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Actualmente cuando hago click en cada imagen de ambas listas, chequeo alguna condición y las agrego a un array. A través de otra función las muestro en un box nuevo. Lo hago así:

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(image) {
  var imagen;
  image.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (!reportList.includes(this)) {
      reportList.push(this);
      if (reportList.length < 2) {
        addMarkerButton.disabled = true;
      } else {
        addMarkerButton.disabled = false;
      }
    } else {
      alert("Element is already in the report");
    }*/
  });
});
```

El problema que no logro resolver es que cuando hago click en las imágenes de la lista UNO, se debería abrir una lista nueva por cada imagen con mas imagenes que debería agregar al array y del array al box.

Lo que intente fue crear las listas nuevas y desde la función anterior agregar las imágenes al array dependiendo del id de la imagen a la que le hago click (hago varios if) pero no funciona. Alguna sugerencia?

HTML COMPLETO:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <input
        type="image"
        id="report-img"
        class="report-img"
        src="pictures/64/sea.png"
        onclick="openReportBox()"
      />
      <div id="report-box" class="report-box" style="display: none">
        <ul id="variableTable" style="display: block">
          <li>
            <img
              id="dirtywater"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua sucia</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="group" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/group.png" />
            <p class="listText">Gente</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="jellyfish"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/jellyfish.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua-vivas</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="waves" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/waves.png" />
            <p class="listText">Olas</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="wind" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/windy.png" />
            <p class="listText">Viento</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="dirtywaterTable" style="display: none">
          <li>
            <img
              id="dirtwater1"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua poco sucia</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="dirtwater2"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua sucia</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="dirtwater3"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua muy sucia</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="groupTable" style="display: none">
          <li>
            <img id="group1" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/group.png" />
            <p class="listText">Poca gente</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="group2" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/group.png" />
            <p class="listText">Gente</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="group3" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/group.png" />
            <p class="listText">Mucha gente</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="jellyfishTable" style="display: none">
          <li>
            <img
              id="jellyfish1"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/jellyfish.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Pocas agua-vivas</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="jellyfish2"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/jellyfish.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Agua-vivasa</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img
              id="jellyfish3"
              class="listImage"
              src="pictures/64/jellyfish.png"
            />
            <p class="listText">Muchas agua-vivas</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="wavesTable" style="display: none">
          <li>
            <img id="waves1" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/waves.png" />
            <p class="listText">Olas pequeñas</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="waves2" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/waves.png" />
            <p class="listText">Olas grandes</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="waves3" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/waves.png" />
            <p class="listText">Olas enormes</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="windTable" style="display: none">
          <li>
            <img id="wind1" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/windy.png" />
            <p class="listText">Poco viento</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="wind2" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/windy.png" />
            <p class="listText">Viento</p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <img id="wind3" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/windy.png" />
            <p class="listText">Mucho viento</p>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!--
          <ul id="fixedTable" style="display: block">
            <li>
              <img id="jet" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/jet.png" />
              <p class="listText">Alquiler de motos</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img
                id="sunumbrella"
                class="listImage"
                src="pictures/64/sunumbrella.png"
              />
              <p class="listText">Alquiler de sombrillas</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img id="toilets" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/toilets.png" />
              <p class="listText">Baños</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img id="volley" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/volley.png" />
              <p class="listText">Cancha de volley</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img id="parador" class="listImage" src="pictures/64/cutlery.png" />
              <p class="listText">Parador</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        -->
        <!--
          <ul id="dirtywaterTable" style="display: block">
            <li>
              <img
                id="parador"
                class="listImage"
                src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
              />
              <p class="listText">Agua poco sucia</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img
                id="parador"
                class="listImage"
                src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
              />
              <p class="listText">Agua sucia</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <img
                id="parador"
                class="listImage"
                src="pictures/64/dirtywater.png"
              />
              <p class="listText">Agua muy sucia</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        -->
        <button id="add-marker" class="add-marker">Add marker</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCOEhho_jnKsgon1s6APsc4_oREVihhnLo&callback=initMap"
      async
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
```

Desde ya gracias por que estoy muy trancado.

Comment: Podrías incluir la estructura del `HTML`?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Ya edite para que aparezca el html de forma completa.

Comment: Comprueba que has quitado el `*/` del código, te generará un error si no lo quitas. También tienes una declaración que no usas: `var imagen;`. Estoy intentando reproducir tu problema, pero no tengo una referencia del código HTML funcionando (todos tus elementos de la lista están ocultos) y una referencia con la lista de listas que no te funciona. Creo que no tenemos el código completo o bien no has explicado bien qué te ocurre.

Comment: Te recomiendo que te pases por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Si no puedes reproducir aquí el problema prueba en http://next.plnkr.co o https://codepen.io , etc.

Comment: Nuevamente gracias por responder. Tal vez no fui lo suficientemente claro. La idea es reproducir algo similar a lo que sucede en la app Waze. Esto significa que cuando hago clic en las imagenes, que se abra una lista nueva con mas opciones para incluir en el reporte. Es por este motivo que hay algunas listas ocultas porque la idea es que se muestren al hacer clic en las imagenes de la lista original. Hay una ultima lista comentada porque la preciso para mas adelante y no quiero que tenga esta funcionalidad.